# achieve mysql dump and restore in one command in golang

Tags: go

i wanted to run this command using golang how can i achieve it using exec.Command

`mysqldump -u root -p database_name | mysql -h remote_host -u root -p remote_database_name`

please anyone help me

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a pipe, which is a shell construct, as a command line argument.

You can execute `bash` with the `-c string` option to execute command in the `string`.

```golang
str := "mysqldump -u root -p database_name | mysql -h remote_host -u root -p remote_database_name"
output, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", str).Output()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(output))
```

Or you can use [`(*exec.Cmd).StdoutPipe`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.StdoutPipe) to pipe the output of one command to the input of another.

```golang
c1 := exec.Command("mysqldump", "-u", "root", "-p", "database_name")
out, err := c1.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

c2 := exec.Command("mysql", "-h", "remote_host", "-u", "root", "-p", "remote_database_name")
c2.Stdin = out

if err := c2.Start(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err := c1.Run(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err := c2.Wait(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try below? Refer [here](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/example_test.go).

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("mysqldump", "-u", "root", "-p", "database_name", "|", "mysql", "-h", "remote_host", "-u", "root", "-p", "remote_database_name")
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil { 
        log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i tried the above as the following still im getting the error Command finished with error: exit status 6